# Select a String between two characters in a string in SQL

Tags: sql

I have data in TABLE A which contains something like below:

**I had a doubt, which, was not confusing, so I needed help, hence I came, to StackOverflow, which cleared my doubt**

Now I want the result to show the data between the 4th and 5th comma.

SO the answer would be **hence I came**

The string can be dynamic as well.
I am not sure how to use `CHARINDEX` on this.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If the string is dynamic, how do you know which comma (4th and 5th) you have to use? Do you have more examples and the query which you have tried?

Comment: That's exactly what  needs to be done , the query should dynamically find the fourth and fifth comma and give me the string between these two commas